# How to clear sessionStorage when navigating to another page but not on refresh?

Tags: javascript, html, session-storage, sessionstorage

I have some check boxes in one of my webpages, and this page has to refresh every 1 minute for some data consistency issues.

I am using `window.sessionStoage` to persist the check boxes that have been checked so that the user doesn't lose the boxes already checked on page refresh.

But I want to clear the `sessionStorage` when the user navigates away from that page (**not necessarily leaving my website, might be going to another page on the same website**), and for the same if I use the `onunload` event then the storage will be cleared in case of refresh also.

Is there any other event or any workaround that could help me achieve this.

Comment: You could use session or local storage to set a variable at the top of the page, to determine whether or not this page is the same page.  And if it is or is not, clear the session.

Answer (score 2):

May you try to save the path/name of the current page in you session-storage and on each init of your page check if the pagename equals the name in the sessionstorage. If not, you can clear it.

Answer (score 1):

For your particular case window events can be in handy. So you can react to the blur and focus events, so leaving your browser tab will cause `blur` event.

```
$(window).blur(function(){
  //clear session
});

$(window).focus(function(){
  //maybe some code to re-init session data
});
```

Comment: I have edited my question, the user might be going to another page on the same website.